# Using Terminal to truncate filenames in directory

Tags: terminal

I have about a thousand jpegs in a directory that have filenames such as

1300-Kazoo-Pkg.jpg
1314-Learn-to-Play-Piano-withKid.jpg
1314-Learn-to-Play-Piano.jpg

I want to shorten them to the numbers before the first hyphen.

I have tried using `for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f/-*.}"; done` but I can't figure out what to add to get done what I want done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I want to shorten them to the numbers before the first” can you clarify what you’d like the output to be?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. The first hyphen.

Comment: What result do you want in the cases where you have filenames with the same prefix? One option is to just skip them. But it seems like you don’t want to do that. So, another option is to append, say, some digits, so that you end up with, e.g.,  `1314-1.jpg`, `1314-2.jpg`, etc. Is that what you want? If so, I can update my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Yes the `1314-1.jpg` and `1314-2.jpg` would be great!

Comment: OK, gimme a minute and I’ll write that up (if somebody doesn’t beat me to it).

Comment: So I did a quick stab at appending a `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, etc., suffix for the cases where there are dupes. Note the limitation I mention in my answer: It just keeps incrementing the suffix value across the whole set of files instead of doing it only per-suffix. I can refine it later if you want but in the mean time anybody else should feel free to either modify my answer with that refinement, or post a follow-up answer with that refinement. (I have to step out for a couple hours now but can help more this later if still needed.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29556/discussion-between-sideshowbarker-and-user1470242).

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I don't know it to go `-1` , `-2` and start over on each set of duplicates if there is a way to just move the duplicates to another folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve the filename extension in the expected way, you should instead do this:

```sh
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f/-*}.jpg"; done
```

That is, use `${f/-*}.jpg` instead of `${f/-*.}`.

To deal with the case of multiple files that have the same prefix before the dash, you can do something like this: *[**Note:** For a better version, see the **Update** I’ve since added after this.]*

```
i=0
for f in *.jpg; do
  if [ "$(ls -l ${f/-*}* | wc -l | xargs)" -gt 1 ]; then
    for g in "${f/-*}"; do
      mv "$f" "$g-$((i++)).jpg"
    done
  else
    if [[ $f == *"-"* ]]; then
      mv "$f" "${f/-*}.jpg"
    fi
  fi
done
```

That will give you output like this:

```
1300.jpg
1314-0.jpg
1314-1.jpg
1315-2.jpg
1315-3.jpg
```

That is, a *`-N`* suffix will get added, though with the limitation that this simple example just keeps incrementing the `N` value across the whole set of files instead of per-prefix.

Also note that you can safely re-run this script multiple times in the same directory and you’ll end up with the same expected filenames in the end (which I think is what you’d want, rather than it monkeying around further with any filenames that are already in the form you want).

---

#### Update

Here’s a better version that just appends 1-*N* suffixes to the renamed files if it finds an existing file with the same basename or same basename+*N* (in which case it increments by *N*+1 and retries).

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  base=${f/-*}
  if [[ -e "${base}.jpg" ]] ; then
    i=1
    while [[ -e "${base}-${i}.jpg" ]]; do
      let i++
    done
    base=$base-$i
  fi
  mv "$f" "${base}.jpg"
done
```

That gives output like this:

```
1300.jpg
1314-1.jpg
1314.jpg
1315-1.jpg
1315-2.jpg
1315.jpg
```

Comment: I responded to your comment.

Comment: @patrix See my updated version, which takes sort of a completely different approach. I think it’s definitely better than what I had slapped together originally.